# how to capture values ​of type int - GO, GIN, POSTFORM

Tags: html, go, struct, go-gin

I'm building a simple crud integrated with html. My crud consists of a table of products, in my table I have the following fields:

```html
package models

type Produtos struct {
    IDProd       int    `json:"id_Prod" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    NomeProduto  string `json:"nome_produto"`
    Quantidade   int    `json:"quantidade"`
    PrecoProduto int    `json:"preco_produto"`
}
```

I'm trying to make a fullstack crud, but I'm stuck in the part where I enter the Quantity and Product_Price values.
My GO code is like this:

```html
package handlers

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/guilherm5/crud/models"
)

func (h Handler) CreateProduct(c *gin.Context) {
    //CREATE IN WEBSITE

    var createHTML = []models.Produtos{{
        NomeProduto:  c.Request.FormValue("nome_produto"),
        Quantidade:   c.Request.FormValue("quantidade"),
        PrecoProduto: c.Request.FormValue("preco_produto")}}

    h.DB.Create(&createHTML)
```

my html code like this:

```html
 <section class="container-principal">
        <form action="/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="title">
                <h1>Crie seu usuario</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="single-input">
                <input placeholder="nome do produto" type="text" id="nome_produto" name="nome_produto">
            </div>

            <div class="single-input">
                <input placeholder="quantidade em estoque" type="number" id="quantidade" name="quantidade">
            </div>

            <div class="single-input">
                <input placeholder="preco do produto" type="number" id="preco_produto" name="preco_produto">
            </div>

            <a class="new" href="/"><button id="botao" type="submit" class="glow-on-hover" type="button">Enviar</button></a>
        </form>
```

my problem is in the GO code, in my Quantity part it is issuing the following error:

my problem is in the GO code, in my Quantity part: `c.Request.FormValue("quantidade")`, it is issuing the following error:

```
cannot use c.Request.FormValue("quantidade") (value of type string) as int value in struct literal
```

the parameter `c.Request.FormValue` does not accept int in its entries, how can I solve this? Is there any other parameter to be used? can someone help me?

Comment: have you tried checking for [Unmarshalling](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding#MapFormWithTag) solutions? go is giving a message that you are trying to assign a value of string to an integer variable. Going through a basic tutorial of parsing Form values in go, should clear your doubts.